# Android - Set size of ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-dialog

I need to show a ProgressDialog when my WebView is loading, so that the user cannot see the page loading in the background. I can only get my dialog to show up as a little box, I would like the dialog to fill up all the space below the action bar.

How can I achieve this? I have used the method `progressDialog.setProgressStyle()` but without any luck.

If there are any other better ways of achieving this, please let me know. My ultimate aim is for the app to behave like the Facebook (pre-native) app, where the 'Loading' indicator was visible until the page had finished loading.

Comment: ProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall); try with this parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding this does not appear to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself. I have used a different method to achieve the same effect. I am not sure whether or not it is best practice, but my webview layout now looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- WebView progress -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/webProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Loading"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And to show and hide the progress I use:

```
View webProgress = findViewById(R.id.webProgress);
```

...

```
public void showWVProgress() {
    webProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isWVProgressShowing = true;     
}

public void hideWVProgress() {
    webProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    isWVProgressShowing = false;
}
```